# PHP is changing the value of my variable because i bind it as a mysqli parameter?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

im tracking down a weird bug where a variable i have is being changed at some point, and this is where I found the problem:

```
echo "2. page is $page<br>";
$h = $page;
//Ok everything is done. Now need to update the view counter
$query = "UPDATE pages SET views=views+1 WHERE id=? LIMIT 1";
if($stmt = $db -> prepare($query))
{
    $stmt -> bind_param("i", $page);
    $stmt ->execute();
    $stmt ->close();
}
else
    dberror();
echo "3. page is $page<br>";
$page = $h;
echo "4. page is $page<br>";
```

So I am getting this:

```
2. page is page
3. page is 0
4. page is page
```

I just added in that $h variable to try and fix the problem and it worked. So for some reason the sql query is destrying my page variable. Does anyone know why this would happen?

Answer (score 4):

You bound it as an integer: `$stmt->bind_param("i", $page);`, but it was actually a string: `"page"`.

`bind_param` binds a reference to the *actual variable*, not a copy of it, to the statement. So it must modify the variable, converting it to an integer to work as a bound integer parameter.

The integer value of `"page"` (in fact, of any string that contains no digits) is `0`, so that's why you see it becoming `0`.

Comment: Related, one of the most annoying parts of php
`<?php
 
if (0 == 'page'){
echo 'true';
}else{
echo 'false';
}
 
?>`
Sample run of the code:
http://ideone.com/1CYzfhqu

Answer (score 0):

`$page` is passed by reference in `bind_param("i", $page);` thus as others mentioned , PHP converted it to int and that's why it was destroyed